# Hitting a wall with a seemingly unforecastable time series: how to deal with it?

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting

I have a time series for which I can't seem to get any good results. I've tried multiple ARIMA models and exponential smoothing models and none of them give good results.

I have 104 weeks of weekly data, and I'm trying to forecast over the next 7~8 weeks. The best I can get is a MAPE of 35%. I want to get it to 20% or better. 
(I've not tried Croston's because sparsity/intemittency isn't an issue).

I' wondering whether there is any benefit to trying more advanced models (and the only more advanced models I can think of are NNets) or not.

If ARIMA doesn't give good results, would a more complex algorithm give any better results? Or is the series just not forecastable ?

What are the approaches for dealing with such a time series?

Is there a way of knowing whether 35% is the best accuracy possible with the series?

(I realize that the question is broad. Although I am trying to solve an immediate problem, I am also look for more general answers, as text books don't seem to address this problem).

Comment: Too vague to be answered. We don't know the domain, the forecast horizon, your expectations for how good a forecast should be, whether the issue is outliers or .... lots of things.

Comment: @zbicyclist I've added some detail. But I'm looking for broad answers.

Comment: Why do you think there could be a model that will get you MAPE of 20%?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I've added some detail.

Comment: Closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179

Answer (score 0):

Often time (read nearly always) untreated level shifts and one-time anomalies create havoc with simple arima model identification. As @AdamO [Interrupted Time Series Analysis - ARIMAX for High Frequency Biological Data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/interrupted-time-series-analysis-arimax-for-high-frequency-biological-data/317804#317804) elegantly wrote the correlogram should be calculated from residuals using a model that controls for intervention administration, otherwise the intervention effects are taken to be Gaussian noise, underestimating the actual autoregressive effect. If you wish I will try and help further by inspecting the actual data. Please post it a csv column format.