# Determine AR term from PACF plot

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima, acf-pacf

I have the a time series data, the acf and pacf for which have been displayed below:
[image]

[image]

I get that MA term is 1. But I'm confused about AR term since it is geometrically decaying from 7th lag. Do I need to transform the data again to eliminate this?

PS: This data has already been differenced once.

Comment: Are these daily data?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your data knows for sure as there may be a weekly deterministic effect (seasonal pulses) and other "features" waiting to be discovered .... post your data and I will try and help further .. The acf and pacf are descriptive but only inferential iff ...no pulses , no level/step shifts , no seasonal pulses . no local time trends , constant error variance and parameters over time

after receipt of your data ( 366 days [image]ily values for 1 year )  .
In summary ...when you have daily data there could be

1. day-of-the-week effects         not provable with your data
2. week-of-the-year effects        not provable with your data
3. month-of-the-year effects       provable
4. day-of-the-month effects        not provable with your data
5. week-if-the-month effects       not provable with your data
6. holiday effects                 not provable with your data
7. long weekend effects            not provable with your data
8. level shift effects             not significant
9. local time trends               not significant
10. arima effects                  not significant
11. differencing effects           not significant
12. pulse effects                  significant
13. paramater changes over time    not provable with your data
14. power transform effects        significant

15  deterministic error var change not provable with your data

16  exogenous variables effect     not provable with your data

The software I used identified a number of pulses ...1 period anomalies . See the Actual and Cleansed graph here [image] . The cleansed series led directly to a seasonal model with 10 predictors using a log transformation [image].

The plot of the residuals is here [image] suggesting reduced variablity during the summer months. The residual acf is here [image]

Responding directly to your question the best arima model is (0,0,0)(0,0,0) with 10 Monthly Seasonal Indicators reflecting deterministic changes through the year.

The pulses that were identified are here : [image] and model summary here [image]

Comment: How do I post a data here?

Comment: If you can't post ...then email it to me and I will try to answer your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dhL0XvGFGWetbJqv-uLnSDZNpojHPh5X

Comment: Here is the google drive link to my data.

Comment: Thanks a lot. From where can I learn time series forecasting (theory and practicals in R/Python) given that I already know some basics.?

Comment: What are pulses that you mentioned? Can I do the same thing you did in R?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335344/how-to-determine-order-of-sarima/335449#335449 contains a discussion why the available tools in R can NOT do the job. I used AUTOBOX which has a commercially available R version to automatically develop the underlying model. A pulse is a one time anomaly. If you wish to contact me offline we can have a discussion about the theory and practice of time series forecasting as I prefer dialogue to monologue. Also you can pursue https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3382/irishstat to read previous discussions on the subject.

Comment: I was intrigued by your ACF plot ... It appears that you mght not know that unwarranted differencing  (of any order ) can INJECT structure into the data rather than clarify the analysis much like putting on somebody else's eye glasses. By differencing unnecessarily of order 7 you created a series whose acf reflects that