# How to interpret following ACF and PACF plots of weekly series data

Tags: r, time-series, acf-pacf

[PACF plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R741f.png)
[image: PACF plot]
[image: ACF]

My data gave me following ACF and PACF plots. How should I interpret them?

Comment: there are a lot of posts regarding interpreting acf and pacf plots on this site already. Your question runs a very very high risk of getting closed as duplicate. Please search this site, i am sue you will get relevant answers.

Comment: Weekly data is often affected by holiday events . The acf and pacf of the original data is often insufficient to identify a good model. Only the data knows for sure. If you post it (include starting date and country if applicable)  I will try and help see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406986/sarima-modelling-results-choosing-the-right-lag-for-seasonal-data for a very similar (but different) question.

Comment: @IrishStat thanks for your response. Starting date of the data is 07 dec 2016 and country is US.

Comment: and the original data is where ?