# What is the correct model (AR, MA, or ARMA) and order for the data?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, autocorrelation, acf-pacf

I am new to time series and forecasting and I have been assigned to determine the model and order for a data object.
The ACF, PACF, and EACF are below:
[image: ACF]

[image: PACF]

[image: EACF]

I was thinking it was an AR(1), but I am not sure.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class? If so, you should include the `self-stuy` tag as it will probably get more views!

Comment: add your data ... and I will try and help further .   auto,arima is of little value as it ASSUMES that the model residuals are free of latent deterministic structure sucha as pulses, level.step shifts , seasonal pulses and/or local time trends  .See @Adamo 's wise words https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317734/interrupted-time-series-analysis-arimax-for-high-frequency-biological-data/317804#317804

Answer (score 1):

By the rough rules of thumb in section 8.5 of [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/), this indeed looks like an AR(1) process:

> The data may follow an ARIMA(p,d,0) model if the ACF and PACF plots of the differenced data show the
>   following patterns:
>
> - the ACF is exponentially decaying or sinusoidal;
> - there is a significant spike at lag p in the PACF, but none beyond lag p.

Try fitting an AR(1) and checking residuals, again using (P)ACF plots.

Alternatively, consider using an automatic ARIMA fitting tool, like `auto.arima()` in the `forecast` package for R.